# Ruby quantify a range

Tags: ruby, range, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Ruby array that defines a set of integer thresholds

```
thresholds = [under_threshold_1, under_threshold_2, ..., under_threshold_n, over_threshold]
```

I want to map any integer to a value corresponding to the threshold number. Basically

```
if threshold_a <  number < threshold_b
  return threshold_a
end
```

Is there a cool way to do that in Ruby ? I Need to handle the "edge" cases `< threshold_1` and `> threshold_over`. I could only come up with a (ugly but working) set of if statements or looping on the array.

I am actually free to modelise this how I want (I can change the array to something else if more convenient)

I was thinking there is maybe a cool way to splat the thresholds in a case/when clause

```
case number
when 0..threshold_1 then 0
when threshold_i..threshold_i+1 then i
else n
end

# example
thresholds  = [ 4, 8, 10 ,12 ]

quantify(1) = 0
quantify(4) = 1 
quantify(11) = 3
quantify(50) = 4
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some examples of the thresholds and the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
thresholds = [ 4, 8, 10, 12 ]

def which_threshold(thresholds, n)
  thresholds.find_index {|t| n < t } || thresholds.size
end

p which_threshold(thresholds, 1)  # => 0
p which_threshold(thresholds, 4)  # => 1
p which_threshold(thresholds, 11) # => 3
p which_threshold(thresholds, 50) # => 4
```

Comment: I prefer what you have, but you could also write `(thresholds+[n+1]).index {|t| n < t }`. Then `which_threshold(thresholds, 8)  #=> 2; which_threshold(thresholds, 14) #=> 4`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's the current output. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I meant you could replace the operative line in your method with the one I mentioned.

Comment: I like the suggested syntax. It's readable and does the job, even saving some time because of the early return. I believe it only works for sorted arrays but this is what I am using anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
Thresholds = [4, 8, 10, 12]

def quantify(n)
  Thresholds.count { |t| n >= t }
end
```

This quantification of n you want happens to be the number of thresholds that n is greater than or equal to, and it's easy to compute that using `Enumerable#count`.

Comment: Of course, this isn't terribly efficient. It will always do `Thresholds.size` comparisons even if `n` is less than `Thresholds[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I prefer Jordan's one (it feels more intuitive), but I believe yours has the advantage of working against an unsorted array, whereas Jordan's one would return too early .

Comment: I like how my answer has less branching in it than Jordan's, so it would be easier to test.